# Netbean error missing semicolon(java comment)

Tags: java, netbeans

Just trying Encog with netbean however I meet some error when build the encog-core-3.2.0

```
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\app\quant\loader\yahoo\YahooDownload.java:58: error: semicolon missing
* The S&P 500.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\engine\network\activation\ActivationElliott.java:35: error: semicolon missing
* http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.7204&rep=rep1&type=pdf
^
```

I don't see a problem with the comment (probably because I'm new to java), or is it only netbean problem? Help is needed

part of the file

```
/**
 * Download financial data from Yahoo.
 */
public class YahooDownload implements MarketLoader, QuantTask {

/**
 * The Dow Jones Industrial Average.
 */
public static final String INDEX_DJIA = "^dji";

/**
 * The S&P 500.
 */
public static final String INDEX_SP500 = "^gspc";

/**
 * The NASDAQ.
 */
public static final String INDEX_NASDAQ = "^ixic";
```

line 58 is `* The S&P 500.`

I'm using netbeans IDE 8.0, with jdk1.8.0_05, jre6.0, jre8.0 installed in my machine.

and btw the full error output here:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 3:24.083s
Finished at: Wed Jun 25 16:43:22 SGT 2014
Final Memory: 22M/82M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:jar (attach-javadocs) on project encog-core: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: warning - Error fetching URL: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\app\analyst\script\process\AnalystProcess.java:41: warning: no description for @return
* @return
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\app\generate\generators\AbstractGenerator.java:92: warning: no description for @param
* @param str
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\app\generate\generators\LanguageSpecificGenerator.java:42: warning: no description for @param
* @param targetFile
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\app\generate\generators\TemplateGenerator.java:38: warning: no description for @param
* @param analyst
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\app\generate\program\EncogProgramArg.java:69: warning: no description for @param
* @param value
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\app\quant\loader\yahoo\YahooDownload.java:58: error: semicolon missing
; The S&P 500.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\engine\network\activation\ActivationElliott.java:35: error: semicolon missing
* http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.7204&rep=rep1&type=pdf
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\engine\network\activation\ActivationElliott.java:35: error: semicolon missing
* http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.7204&rep=rep1&type=pdf
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\engine\network\activation\ActivationElliottSymmetric.java:35: error: semicolon missing
* http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.7204&rep=rep1&type=pdf
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\engine\network\activation\ActivationElliottSymmetric.java:35: error: semicolon missing
* http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.7204&rep=rep1&type=pdf
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ensemble\Ensemble.java:149: warning: no description for @param
* @param setNumber
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ensemble\Ensemble.java:158: warning: no description for @param
* @param memberNumber
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ensemble\Ensemble.java:167: warning: no description for @param
* @param newMember
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ensemble\Ensemble.java:168: warning: no description for @throws
* @throws NotPossibleInThisMethod
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ensemble\Ensemble.java:176: warning: no description for @param
* @param input
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ensemble\Ensemble.java:198: warning: no description for @param
* @param aggregator
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ensemble\EnsembleML.java:76: warning: no @param for testset
public double getError(EnsembleDataSet testset);
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ensemble\EnsembleML.java:76: warning: no @return
public double getError(EnsembleDataSet testset);
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\ComplexNumber.java:172: error: malformed HTML
The principal branch is the branch with -pi < arg <= pi.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\ComplexNumber.java:172: error: malformed HTML
The principal branch is the branch with -pi < arg <= pi.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\ComplexNumber.java:182: error: malformed HTML
is the value with 0 <= arg < pi.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\ComplexNumber.java:182: error: malformed HTML
is the value with 0 <= arg < pi.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\VectorAlgebra.java:144: warning: no @param for maxValue
public void randomise(double[] v, double maxValue) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\dimension\DimensionConstraint.java:49: warning: no description for @param
* @param theLower
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\dimension\DimensionConstraint.java:50: warning: no description for @param
* @param theUpper
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\error\ErrorCalculation.java:176: warning: no @param for significance
public final void updateError(final double[] actual, final double[] ideal, final double significance) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\LUDecomposition.java:341: error: unknown tag: c
* Solves a set of equation systems of type <c>A * X = B</c>.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\LUDecomposition.java:341: error: unknown tag: c
* Solves a set of equation systems of type <c>A * X = B</c>.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\LUDecomposition.java:342: error: unknown tag: c
* @return Matrix <c>X</c> so that <c>L * U * X = B</c>.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\LUDecomposition.java:342: error: unknown tag: c
* @return Matrix <c>X</c> so that <c>L * U * X = B</c>.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\LUDecomposition.java:342: error: unknown tag: c
* @return Matrix <c>X</c> so that <c>L * U * X = B</c>.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\LUDecomposition.java:342: error: unknown tag: c
* @return Matrix <c>X</c> so that <c>L * U * X = B</c>.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\LUDecomposition.java:32: error: bad use of '>'
* For an m-by-n matrix A with m >= n, the LU decomposition is an m-by-n unit
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\LUDecomposition.java:34: error: malformed HTML
* permutation vector piv of length m so that A(piv,:) = L*U. If m < n, then L
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\QRDecomposition.java:32: error: bad use of '>'
* For an m-by-n matrix A with m >= n, the QR decomposition is an m-by-n
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\SingularValueDecomposition.java:61: error: bad use of '>'
* For an m-by-n matrix A with m >= n, the singular value decomposition is an
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\SingularValueDecomposition.java:65: error: bad use of '>'
* The singular values, sigma[k] = S[k][k], are ordered so that sigma[0] >=
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\SingularValueDecomposition.java:66: error: bad use of '>'
* sigma[1] >= ... >= sigma[n-1].
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\decomposition\SingularValueDecomposition.java:66: error: bad use of '>'
* sigma[1] >= ... >= sigma[n-1].
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\matrices\hessian\BasicHessian.java:125: warning: no description for @param
* @param d
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\randomize\Randomizer.java:99: warning: no description for @param
* @param theRandom
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\randomize\Randomizer.java:109: warning: no description for @param
* @param seed
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\randomize\RandomChoice.java:90: warning: no @param for theGenerator
public int generate(Random theGenerator) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\mathutil\randomize\RandomChoice.java:115: warning: no @param for theGenerator
public int generate(Random theGenerator, int skip) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\bayesian\BayesianNetwork.java:789: warning: no description for @param
* @param line
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\bayesian\parse\ParsedEvent.java:54: warning: no description for @param
* @param theLabel
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\bayesian\parse\ParseProbability.java:146: warning: no description for @param
* @param line
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\bayesian\query\enumerate\EnumerationQuery.java:246: warning: no @param for enumerationEvents
public static boolean roll(List<BayesianEvent> enumerationEvents, int[] args) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\bayesian\query\enumerate\EnumerationQuery.java:246: warning: no @param for args
public static boolean roll(List<BayesianEvent> enumerationEvents, int[] args) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\data\buffer\codec\DataSetCODEC.java:57: warning: no @param for significance
void write(double[] input, double[] ideal, double significance);
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\data\sparse\SparseMLData.java:64: warning: no @param for i
public SparseMLData(final double[] d, int[] i) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\ea\exception\EACompileError.java:37: warning: no description for @param
* @param msg
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\util\obj\ChooseObject.java:83: warning: no description for @param
* @param theGenerator
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\ea\population\BasicPopulation.java:88: warning: no @param for theGenomeFactory
public BasicPopulation(final int thePopulationSize,
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\factory\MLMethodFactory.java:63: error: bad HTML entity
* A probabilistic neural network. Supports both PNN & GRNN.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\genetic\genome\DoubleArrayGenome.java:55: warning: no description for @param
* @param other
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\hmm\HiddenMarkovModel.java:51: error: semicolon missing
* such as interest rate and the level of the S&P500. The HMM learns what state
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\prg\EncogProgramContext.java:326: error: bad HTML entity
*         This defines the set of functions & operators that a program
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\prg\EncogProgramContext.java:50: error: bad HTML entity
* the set of functions & operators that a program might use. For an Encog
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\prg\expvalue\ExpressionValue.java:155: warning: no @param for enumType
public ExpressionValue(final int enumType, final long theValue) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\prg\extension\FunctionFactory.java:196: error: bad use of '>'
* This method is used when parsing an expression. Consider x>=2. The parser
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\prg\extension\FunctionFactory.java:197: error: bad use of '>'
* first sees the > symbol. But it must also consider the =. So we first
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\train\strategy\end\EarlyStoppingStrategy.java:133: warning: no description for @param
* @param theValidationSet
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\train\strategy\end\EarlyStoppingStrategy.java:134: warning: no description for @param
* @param theTestSet
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\train\strategy\RequiredImprovementStrategy.java:109: warning: no description for @param
* @param cycles
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\error\ErrorFunction.java:35: warning: no description for @param
* @param actual
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\error\ErrorFunction.java:36: warning: no description for @param
* @param error
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\freeform\FreeformNetwork.java:734: warning: no description for @param
* @param task
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\hyperneat\substrate\Substrate.java:100: warning: no description for @param
* @param theDimensions
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\neat\NEATPopulation.java:248: warning: no description for @param
* @param populationSize
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\neat\training\opp\NEATCrossover.java:104: warning: no @param for best
public void addNeuronID(final long nodeID, final List<NEATNeuronGene> vec,
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\neat\training\opp\NEATCrossover.java:104: warning: no @param for notBest
public void addNeuronID(final long nodeID, final List<NEATNeuronGene> vec,
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\neat\training\opp\NEATMutation.java:152: warning: no @param for target
public int getElementPos(final NEATGenome target, final long neuronID) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\neat\training\opp\NEATMutation.java:189: warning: no @param for target
public boolean isDuplicateLink(final NEATGenome target,
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\layers\BasicLayer.java:52: error: bad use of '>'
* Input1->Hidden1Weight) + (Input2Output * Input2->Hidden1Weight) +
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\layers\BasicLayer.java:52: error: bad use of '>'
* Input1->Hidden1Weight) + (Input2Output * Input2->Hidden1Weight) +
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\layers\BasicLayer.java:57: error: bad use of '>'
* Hidden2Activation = (Input1Output * Input1->Hidden2Weight) + (Input2Output *
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\layers\BasicLayer.java:58: error: bad use of '>'
* Input2->Hidden2Weight) + (HiddenBiasActivation * Hidden2BiasWeight)
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\layers\BasicLayer.java:64: error: bad use of '>'
* Output1Activation = (Hidden1Output * Hidden1->Output1Weight)
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\layers\BasicLayer.java:66: error: bad use of '>'
* Hidden2->Output1Weight) + (OutputBiasActivation * Output1BiasWeight)
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\training\concurrent\jobs\TrainingJob.java:91: warning: no @param for singleThreaded
public abstract void createTrainer(boolean singleThreaded);
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\training\concurrent\performers\ConcurrentTrainingPerformerCPU.java:64: warning: no description for @param
* @param number
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\training\lma\LevenbergMarquardtTraining.java:164: warning: no @param for h
public LevenbergMarquardtTraining(final BasicNetwork network,
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\training\pnn\DeriveMinimum.java:38: error: bad HTML entity
* John Wiley & Sons Inc (Computers); April 3, 1995 ISBN: 0471105880
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\training\pnn\GlobalMinimumSearch.java:84: error: bad use of '>'
*            Brent's tolerance, must be >= sqrt( eps )
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\training\pnn\GlobalMinimumSearch.java:35: error: bad HTML entity
* John Wiley & Sons Inc (Computers); April 3, 1995 ISBN: 0471105880
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\training\propagation\GradientWorker.java:150: warning: no @param for flatSpot
public GradientWorker(final FlatNetwork theNetwork,
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\training\propagation\GradientWorker.java:150: warning: no @param for ef
public GradientWorker(final FlatNetwork theNetwork,
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\networks\training\pso\NeuralPSO.java:497: warning: no description for @param
* @param initialPopulation
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\pnn\BasicPNN.java:56: error: bad HTML entity
* by Timothy Masters, PhD (http://www.timothymasters.info/) John Wiley & Sons
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\neural\rbf\RBFNetwork.java:250: warning: no @param for t
public void setRBFCentersAndWidthsEqualSpacing(final double minPosition,
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\parse\tags\Tag.java:187: error: malformed HTML
* Convert this tag back into string form, with the beginning < and ending
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\parse\tags\Tag.java:188: error: bad use of '>'
* >.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\persist\EncogDirectoryPersistence.java:278: warning: no @param for obj
public final void saveToDirectory(final String name, final Object obj) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\util\file\ResourceInputStream.java:43: warning: no @return
public static InputStream openResourceInputStream(final String resource) {
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\util\normalize\target\NormalizationStorage.java:43: warning: no @param for norm
void open(DataNormalization norm);
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\util\simple\EncogUtility.java:457: warning: no description for @param
* @param f
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\util\simple\EncogUtility.java:458: warning: no description for @param
* @param data
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\util\text\Base64.java:1143: warning: no @throws for java.io.IOException
public static byte[] decode( byte[] source )
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\util\text\Base64.java:35: error: self-closing element not allowed
* <br />
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\util\text\Base64.java:1697: error: unexpected end tag: </i>
*     (only meaningful when encoding)</i>
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\util\text\Base64.java:1910: error: unexpected end tag: </i>
*     (only meaningful when encoding)</i>
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\ml\prg\EncogProgramContext.java:74: error: bad HTML entity
* defines the set of functions & operators that a program might use. For an
^

Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\target\apidocs' dir.
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: That seems strange. Could you post a few additional lines before that comment and point out which line is 58 exactly?

Comment: added additional lines before the comment

Comment: and btw my netbeans is netbeans IDE 8.0

Comment: try `javac YahooDownload.java` and print traceback here.

Comment: Allright, that's really really strange. I'm not an Netbeans expert but if I paste the relevant lines into my Eclipse it compiles just fine.

Comment: I tried compile from command line `javac YahooDownload.java` and not get any problem

Comment: still figuring how to `javac YahooDownload.java` in netbeans

Comment: Javadoc content is supposed to be HTML, and '&' is something you need to encode in HTML as '&amp;' (note the ';' there to indicate the end of the entity reference!). It might be that the netbeans compiler is a bit more aggressive in enforcing that.

Comment: maybe your right, even '<' or '>' also will generate error when building in netbeans

Comment: I tested our code in Netbeans 8.0 and it worked for me

Comment: hmm could it be some of my extension messed up java configuration? The netbean I use is with java, php, C++ and etc. Btw added full error output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not the java compilation, but the javadoc compilation, and in particular the "doclint" feature of javadoc from the Java 8 JDK.

You have multiple options:

1. Fix the javadoc errors :)
2. Disable the doclint feature, essentially add `-Xdoclint:none` to the invocation of javadoc (http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html for various ways)

Answer (score 16):

Regarding the `error: semicolon missing` errors you received :

```
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\app\quant\loader\yahoo\YahooDownload.java:58: error: semicolon missing
* The S&P 500.
^
C:\Users\v\Documents\encog-core-3.2.0\src\main\java\org\encog\engine\network\activation\ActivationElliott.java:35: error: semicolon missing
* http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.7204&rep=rep1&type=pdf
^
```

Note that Javadoc comment [text must be written in HTML with HTML entities and HTML tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#JSWOR647)

These particular errors are due to the ampersand(s) present in the offending lines, as when your Javadoc comments are being translated into HTML it is expecting that the ampersand is the beginning of an [HTML Entity](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) and thus should be terminated with a semicolon.

**Solution:** replace all ampersands in your comments with the HTML entity `&amp;`

Comment: Thank you for this.  I never would have noticed this in my code without this answer.